# Searching for an app that will act as a "tcp tunnel/relay"

Tags: windows, networking, web-server

I have a situation where I have 4 clients. client A which wants to talk to client A1 , and client B which want to talk to client B1. all of these clients are behind firewalls. therefore I need a server that will be available for both sides (as an intermediate) and will listen on port X for connections from Clients A and B and once connected it will wait for client A1 or B1 to connect on port Y, then the server will be in charge of transmitting the data from client A to A1 and B to B1. also, the server must have the ability to handle multiple connections at the same time and to enforce secured connection. lastly, the connection must be persistent (using socket).

Comment: Created a drawing to represent the network/solution setup http://imgur.com/DX6R69G